# Convert appended text to Date

Tags: t-sql

```
  convert(datetime,  BIRTH_MM + '/' +  BIRTH_DD + '/' + BIRTH_YY, 103) as Birthdate
```

So the concatenated string looks like this: `04/05/88`

trying to get this working.

tried this, close I now get a date but it's giving me 1900 for the year or 1905 which is not right

```
convert(datetime,  BIRTH_MM + BIRTH_DD + BIRTH_YY, 103) as Birthdate
```

UPDATE

tried something out, not quite there yet:

```
 case when(BIRTH_DD > 0 and BIRTH_MM > 0 and BIRTH_YY > 0)
    then 
            convert(datetime, cast(BIRTH_DD as varchar(1)) + '/' + cast(_BIRTH_MM as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(BIRTH_YY as varchar(4)), 103)
    else
            convert(datetime, '1900-01-01', 103) as Birthdate,
        end
```

Comment: are `BIRTH_MM`, `BIRTH_DD` and `BIRTH_YY` columns in a table?  Where does this come from?

Comment: this is part of a query.  It has to be columns in a table...T-SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing your table structures or datatype on those values, you can use something similar to this:

```
declare @BIRTH_MM int = 04
declare @BIRTH_DD int = 05
declare @BIRTH_YY int = 1988

select convert(datetime,
               cast(@BIRTH_MM as varchar(2)) + '/' +  
               cast(@BIRTH_DD as varchar(2)) + '/' + 
               cast(@BIRTH_YY as varchar(4)), 101) as Birthdate
```

see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5606)

Comment: the fields are type int in the DB

Comment: @CoffeeAddict this this conversion should work.  The demo has the values as int

Comment: tried this, doesn't work 
convert(datetime, cast(BIRTH_DD as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(BIRTH_MM as varchar(2)) + '/' + cast(BIRTH_YY as varchar(4)), 103) as Birthdate

Comment: is your `BIRTH_YY` four characters or 2?

Comment: it gives me 0/0/0 for the cast and / string

Comment: @CoffeeAddict can you post some sample data from those columns?

Comment: crap there is some bad data.  Some have 0s for all 3 errr

Comment: @CoffeeAddict you should place your code updates in your question not in the answer.

Comment: blufeet usually I do, yea I know